# Is dependencies order make any change in the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

What if we change the order of the dependencies is that will make any change in the app?

[image]

Comment: Will change nothing!

Comment: "What if we change the order of the dependencies" ...... what, why??  If there is a conflict, there's a conflict no matter what ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not make any difference, as long as they are on the list, it does not matter what position in order they are.